# How do I use struct and arrays to fill a file using fwrite function in C?

Tags: c, fwrite

I want to create a program that fills a file with properties of 5 students ( matricule , firstname , lastname ) using **fwrite()**, i tried to solve that using struct with arrays as shown bellow :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    struct Student
    {
        char* matricule;
        char* nom ;
        char* prenom;
    };

    Student student[4];

    student[0].matricule = "m001";
    student[0].nom = "Boussaha";
    student[0].prenom = "Borhanedine";

    student[1].matricule = "m002";
    student[1].nom = "Toaba";
    student[1].prenom = "Anes";

    student[2].matricule = "m003";
    student[2].nom = "Laamari";
    student[2].prenom = "Loqmane";

    student[3].matricule = "m004";
    student[3].nom = "Dellachi";
    student[3].prenom = "Amir";

    student[4].matricule = "m005";
    student[4].nom = "Zenfour";
    student[4].prenom = "Abdelmouiz";

    
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("list.data" , "wb");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fwrite(student[i].matricule , sizeof(student[i].matricule) , 5 , f);
        fwrite(student[i].nom , sizeof(student[i].nom) , 5 , f);
        fwrite(student[i].prenom , sizeof(student[i].prenom) , 5 , f);
    }
}
```

I guess and hope nothing is wrong in the code.

When I debug the program, the file gets created but I find it empty. I am wondering why it is empty when I was expecting the file to be filled with the properties of each student?

Comment: As your file is probably a text file, you should use `fprintf` to write to the file.

Comment: how to solve it using fwrite? because i am asked to solve it using fwrite only

Comment: `Student student[4];` That's... unh... only room for 4 students...

Comment: @borhanedine using `fwrite` for writing  to a text file doesn't make make much sense. You need to tell us what the `list.txt` is suposed to contain. [Edit] and make that clear.

Comment: @Jabberwocky well it is actually .data but i still get the same problem

Comment: Have you thought about using `strlen()` instead of `sizeof`? And change the 5 in the `fwrite()` commands to be only 1.... Of course, without also writing an SP or LF between/after every output, it's all going to just ram itself together...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Still not working

Comment: "Still not working" after WHAT? What did you change? Did you increase the allocation as I commented above? What?

Comment: You need to write `strlen+1` bytes to your file. Otherwise you would just concatenate all the strings in the file and would not be able to separate them when you read the file. Of course, writing 5 items does not make any sense (as Fe203 mentioned) as you only write one string in each call.

Comment: You should also properly close your file. And did you fix the size of your array?

Comment: @Gerhardh how should i use **strlen**

Comment: What *exactly* is unclear after you read the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) (or the corresponding standard section) for `strlen`? You were told you need to replace `sizeof` with `strlen`. That means it should be clear where to put it: `fwrite(student[i].nom , 1, strlen(student[i].nom)+1, f);`

Comment: @Gerhardh What's the plan for retrieving the data from the file?

Comment: @oka: What about reading chunks of data and looking for 0 bytes to separate the strings? How else would you store and read strings of unknown size?

Comment: @Gerhardh I did what you said but still not working; by the way when I try to debug the compilation pauses automatically in **CALL STACK (Visual Studio)** I do not why, and I will have to click on resume.

Comment: There have been multiple suggestions and no one knows how your code looks now. Please add an update version to your question. Do not delete the initial code but add below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Student student[4];` allocates enough room for 4 elements. This means `student[0]` through `student[3]` is valid, but `student[4]` is not valid. Accessing `student[4]` effectively makes you program behave unpredictably. Set it to `Student student[5]`.
- `f = fopen("list.data" , "wb");` is okay, but did you check for errors?  `if(f==0)` then an error has occurred. Better safe than sorry.
- `fwrite(student[i].XYZ , sizeof(student[i].XYZ) , 5 , f);` is very wrong. I'm not sure if you're new to C but I can tell you that `sizeof` does not do what you think it does. And I bet you don't seem to know why that `5` is there either. Replace `sizeof` with `strlen`, and replace `5` with `1`.

Comment: thank you now it works, and yes, I am new to C and i did not now what toput exactly as parameters in the function fwrite.

Comment: now i have a new problem which is when i enter to the file the data is written with like Japanese language or i do not know, and i want it with English alphabets, how can i fix that?

Comment: @borhanedine this answer simply repeats what was already mentioned in comments and where your last response was that you tried that without success. Why is it working now and why didn't you show your updated code to allow anyone to find your remaining issue?